# How do I fetch the latest repeated entry of a record in bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table where in all the updates are pushed as new entries. And table's scema is something of this sort:

```
 [
  {
    "id":"221212",
    "fieldsData": [
      {
        "key": "someDate",
        "value": "12-12-2022"
      },
      {
        "key": "someString",
        "value": "ABCDEF"
      }
    ],
    "name": "Sample data 1",
    "createdOn":"12-11-2022",
    "insertedDate": "14-11-2022",
    "updatedOn": "14-11-2022"
  },
   {
    "id":"221212",
    "fieldsData": [
      {
        "key": "someDate",
        "value": "12-12-2022"
      },
      {
        "key": "someString",
        "value": "ABCDEF"
      },
      {
        "key": "someMoreString",
        "value": "12qwwe122"
      }
    ],
    "name": "Sample data 1",
    "createdOn":"12-11-2022",
    "insertedDate": "15-11-2022",
    "updatedOn": "15-11-2022"
  }
]
```

It is partitioned by month using the createdOn field. The fieldsData field is generic and can have any number of records/fields as separate rows.

How do I fetch the latest entry of id = 221212 and get the repeated records of only the latest one?

I know I can use flatten but flatten queries all the records and that beats the purpose of having a partitioned table.

The query I've got right now is:

```
select * from 
(
SELECT 
id, createdAt, createdBy, fields.key, fields.value,
DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY insertedDate DESC)AS Rank1
FROM `mytableName` , UNNEST(fieldsData) as fields
WHERE createdAt IS NULL or DATE(createdAt) = CURRENT_DATE()
)
where rank1 = 1
```

PS: This table is going to have almost 10k records pushed everyday.

Comment: Has your issue been resolved?

Comment: No, I'm still using the same query.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this serves your purpose.

```
SELECT AS value ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY insertedDate DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)]
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: I will try this and let you know. Thanks for the reply though!